# PyQt4 Using button to change current window contents

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

So I am using PyQt4 to design part of a data warehouse. I would like to have a button that clears all current window contents and replaces it with new contents using the same window. Here is my code:

```
    import sys
    import ETL
    import urllib
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *

    def on_click():
        #change window contents to new contents

        # Creates text that says "Hello"
        Text = QLabel("Hello", Window)
        # Text is moved to coordinates 21, 30
        Text.move(21, 30)


    # Creates PyQt4 Application object
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create Window object
    Window = QWidget()
    Window.resize(320, 240)

    # Creates button object called "Submit"
    Button = QPushButton('Submit', Window)
    # Moves button (Right, Down)
    Button.move(200, 180)
    # When button's clicked executes function called on_click()
    Button.clicked.connect(on_click)

    # Displays window
    Window.show()
    # Needed so the gui window stays open until user closes it
    App.exec_()
```

So after the button is pressed. The button would disappear. The text "Hello" would appear at coordinates 21,30 and the windows size of 320, 240 would remain the same. That is what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import urllib
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


def on_click():
    #change window contents to new contents

    # Creates text that says "Hello"
    text = QLabel('Hello', Window)
    # Text is moved to coordinates 21, 30
    text.move(21, 30)
    QLabel.show(text)
    button.hide()



# Creates PyQt4 Application object
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create Window object
Window = QWidget()
Window.resize(320, 240)

# Creates button object called "Submit"
button = QPushButton('Submit', Window)
# Moves button (Right, Down)
button.move(200, 180)
# When button's clicked executes function called on_click()
button.clicked.connect(on_click)

# Displays window
Window.show()
# Needed so the gui window stays open until user closes it
App.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew it had to be really simple.